# Set border for NSTextField

Tags: swift, nstextfield

Wow, I've really fallen down the rabbit hole. I'm trying to have text on the background of part of a UI and a text field as another part, e.g. the birthday in:

[image]

I then want to repurpose that text filed to allow text entry. So I do something like:

```
myTextFieldName.editable = true
myTextFieldName.backgroundColor = NSColor.textBackgroundColor()
```

and I get something like:
[image]

Which is all well and good, but then I note the nice thin border around the text field below it. So I think, I need a border! I add one with:

```
myTextFieldName.bordered = true
```

...and I get:

[image]

Pow! What a hideous strange thick border! It doesn't look like the default text field border at all! For the life of me, I can't figure out how to make the border of my "activated" text field match that of the default. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Need to set border and border color:

```
myTextFieldName.wantsLayer = true
myTextFieldName.layer?.borderColor = NSColor(red:204.0/255.0, green:204.0/255.0, blue:204.0/255.0, alpha:1.0).cgColor
myTextFieldName.layer?.borderWidth = 1.0
myTextFieldName.layer?.cornerRadius = 0.0
```

Set corner radius if you want rounded corner.

Comment: Now I'm really falling down the rabbit hole trying to access the layer for the text box, but thanks!

Comment: I just saw your question.. You may need to add: `myTextFieldName.needsLayer = true`

Comment: Whoa...  I didn't know you could use UIColor with NSTextField.

Answer (score 1):

You can add borders to NSTextfield and customise it according how you want it.

```
 let border = CALayer()
 border.borderColor =  NSColor.gray.cgColor
 border.autoresizingMask = [.layerHeightSizable, .layerWidthSizable]
 border.borderWidth = 1.0

 myTextFieldName.wantsLayer = true
 myTextFieldName.layer?.addSublayer(border)
 myTextFieldName.layer?.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Because you set the frame explicitly this will break as soon as the size of the NSTextField changes if the frame is not updated.