# Custom Border on NSTextField

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

I want to customise the border of NSTextFields. I have searched around and am fairly sure this needs to be done within the NSTextFieldCell in `drawInterior(withFrame:in:)`, but am not sure how.

Specifically I want a bottom border only, slightly thicker than normal.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841251/set-border-for-nstextfield?

Comment: I’ve seen this, but if you try it and read the comments this approach is causing a whole slew of other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably read the documentation for the `NSCell`. It says that you must draw the border in the `draw(withFrame:in)` function and you must invoke `drawInterior(withFrame:in:)` if you override `draw(withFrame:in)`. Additionally you must override `cellSize` and return the appropriate size that takes your new border into account. I updated the example to the full solution. Created a sample project on [Github](https://github.com/timtwotoes/CustomTextFieldBorder)

```
/**
 Creates an custom border, that is just a line underneath the NSTextField.
 */
class CustomBorderTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {
    // How thick should the border be
    let borderThickness: CGFloat = 3

    // Add extra height, to accomodate the underlined border, as the minimum required size for the NSTextField
    override var cellSize: NSSize {
        let originalSize = super.cellSize
        return NSSize(width: originalSize.width, height: originalSize.height + borderThickness)
    }

    // Render the custom border for the NSTextField
    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        // Area that covers the NSTextField itself. That is the total height minus our custom border size.
        let interiorFrame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellFrame.width, height: cellFrame.height - borderThickness)

        let path = NSBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = borderThickness
        // Line width is at the center of the line.
        path.move(to: NSPoint(x: 0, y: cellFrame.height - (borderThickness / 2)))
        path.line(to: NSPoint(x: cellFrame.width, y: cellFrame.height - (borderThickness / 2)))
        NSColor.black.setStroke()
        path.stroke()

        // Pass in area minus the border thickness in the height
        drawInterior(withFrame: interiorFrame, in: controlView)
    }
}
```

This is the result
[image: Custom NSTextField Border]

Answer (score 0):

You can add your text field a background image and set your border style none.

Answer (score 0):

Add to NSTableHeaderCell this code

```
override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect,
                     in controlView: NSView) {
    let path = NSBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = borderWidth
    // Line width is at the center of the line.
    path.move(to: NSPoint(x: cellFrame.minX, y: cellFrame.minY))
    path.line(to: NSPoint(x: cellFrame.maxX, y: cellFrame.minY))
    NSColor.black.setStroke()
    path.stroke()

    self.drawInterior(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
  }
```